# Axios.delete() not triggering as expected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

So I've got a classes `Model` which contains an array of people who will attend the class, I am trying to remove people from the classes.

So this is the `Model`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const classMembersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  }
})

const classSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  location: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  time: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  classMembers: [classMembersSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('createClass', classSchema);
```

The classMembers Array is the one I mentioned that I am trying to remove members from. `classMembers: [classMembersSchema]`.

This is the `axios.delete`:

```
deleteClassHandler = () => {
    axios.delete('/api/classes/' + this.props.id + '/user/' + this.props.userId)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

This is the `route`:

```
router.delete('/:id/user/:userId', ClassesController.deleteUser);
```

This is the `controller`:

```
exports.deleteUser = (req, res) => {
  GymClass.findById({
    _id: req.params.id
  }, 'classMembers', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(401).json({
        message: "Error Occured!"
      })
    } else {
      GymClass.findByIdAndDelete({
        "classMembers.userId" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId)
      }, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Keeps hitting here!');
            res.status(401).json({
              message: "Error Occured!"
            })
        } else {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Success!"
          })
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Everything works fine until it hits the `console.log('Keeps hitting here!');` 
At the start of the function the `req.params.id` which is the class Id of which class we want to modify and the `req.params.userId` which is the user we want to remove from the Array inside the Model do have the right values but when it gets to that step it gives me the `Error`.

I'm thinking it could be that it is not finding this:

```
GymClass.findByIdAndDelete({
      "classMembers.userId" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId)
```

Since it's in an Array within the `classMembers`. Any idea or advice to get this to work? Many thanks.

Comment: Mongoose actually "autocasts" things like `ObjectId` by comparing the given field path to the schema, so you don't need the manual casting here and can just use the `req.params.userId` just like you did with `req.params.id`. However what you actually appear to want here is "remove the user from the array", which is actually an `update()` with `$pull` and not a "delete" as you are attempting here. As for the general "keeps hitting here" message, then how about you actually log the `err` value instead and see what it actually says. Probably something about the 'casting error'.

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn, Sorry I do not have much experience in this field that's why I asked, would you be able to give me a bit of a hand? I have read what you put but I am still struggling, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps people can give a better explanation if you give a better example. Show a sample document in your collection(s) ( plural since you actually have references to a `'user'` model in there ) you have which would match your expected input and then show what you expect to happen to those document(s) as a result of hitting this route. Then answers can be very specific in guiding you.

Comment: @NeilLunn Does this look better?  `GymClass.findOneAndUpdate({
          "classMembers.userId" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId),
          },
        {
          $pull : { "classMembers" : { userId : req.params.userId } }`

Comment: Working now, thanks @NeilLunn, If you want to type up the answer feel free to do so, it might help others out there... Thanks

Comment: "Looks better" is not exactly the point here now is it? What matters is 1. Does it work? 2. Is it doing what you expect? This is why I asked you to edit your question and show "by example" what exactly you expect to happen. If you're not that confident with the syntax, then a "picture paints a thousand words" as the saying goes. But not an actual "screenshot picture" of course, and just the "text" representing the documents before and after the update action.